# Using OleDDataReader to pull specific data from a database using a SQL command, C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, oledb

I am working on a project, where I want to use a SQL command string to sort through my database in ascending order according to one of the columns and then use another command to get the first value that is greater than or equal to a measured value.

For some reason or another my code only prints out 1, no matter what I change the value that is being measured against the database to. I'm not sure if there is an issue with my second SQL command string or if I am messing up with the OleDb Get methods.

I am a bit rusty with my programing so, additional advice would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
bool renew; 

string conn = TableSettings.Instance.GetConnectionString();
string readingInDoubles = lblReading.Text;
double dNumber;

renew = Double.TryParse(readingInDoubles, out dNumber);
string SqlCmdSort = "SELECT * FROM Tables ORDER BY Mass ASC";
string SqlCmdCompare = "SELECT * FROM Tabels WHERE Mass >= " + renew; 
            
using (OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(conn))
{ 
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(SqlCmdSort, connect);
    OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand(SqlCmdCompare, connect);

    connect.Open();

    OleDbDataReader sort = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (sort.Read())
    {
        OleDbDataReader compare = command2.ExecuteReader();
        compare.Read();
        // compare.GetDouble(0); ignore this. 
        lblUpperValue.Text = compare[0].ToString();
        compare.Close();
    }

    sort.Close();
    connect.Close();
}
```

Comment: As `renew` is a bool, isn't your SQL going to be `SELECT * FROM Tabels WHERE Mass >= true` ?

Comment: @stuartd it does, I did that because VS was underlining it in red when I called renew a double. Is there a way you would change that? Cause it had me stumped for a while.

Comment: Use parameterized queries. Also check your table name - one may be misspelled.

Comment: I don’t really get what you’re doing here, but shouldn’t you be passing `dNumber` to the query instead of `renew`?

Comment: Try replacing this line: `string SqlCmdCompare = "SELECT * FROM Tabels WHERE Mass >= " + renew;` with `string SqlCmdCompare = "SELECT * FROM Tabels WHERE Mass >= " + dNumber.ToString();`

Comment: @stuartd What I am trying to do is use the data being displayed from the label that I created (which is pulling data from a scale) and use that number in the sql command, then I am trying to get the first number from the database that is greater than or equal to the number that was measured and displayed to the label. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user9938 can I get an example of parameterized queries? While I was doing my research and looking for answers I came across that a lot, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @jjthebig1 I am going to give that a shot and I will let you know how that turns out.

Comment: _[I want to] get the first value that is greater than or equal to a measured value_ - `SELECT * FROM Tabels WHERE Mass >= {value}` will get **all** the rows greater or equal to the value. To just get one, use something like `select top 1 * from Tabels where Mass >= {value} order by Mass ASC`

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: @stuartd your comment was the fix that I needed. I will post the working code. Thank you!!!